# How to compare each cell in Line2 with Line1

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing a script which will go thru every cell in line2 and find same in Line1 with counting how many is same. 
Now i am stuck.

```
Sub compare()
final_col = Cells(7, 250).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim Line1 As Range
Dim Line2 As Range
Match = 0

Line1 = Range(Cells(4, 7), Cells(7, final_col))
Line2 = Range(Cells(12, 7), Cells(7, final_col))

For Each i In Line2
   For Each j In Line1
      If i = j Then
         Match = +1
      End If
   Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

What will be best way to fulfill data into for each loops.

Comment: Then you'll want `i` and `j` to be `As Range`, and that will fix the `For Each` loops. And since you're dealing with an object, you will want to have explicit member calls, so `If i.Value = j.Value Then Match = Match + 1` - but first you need to be sure that `Not(IsError(i.Value) Or IsError(j.Value))`, otherwise you risk a  *type mismatch* run-time error if the worksheet contains cell errors.

Comment: As for a better way, I'd suggest you start by dump the entire range's values into a 2D `Variant` array, and then iterating that array (using a `For...Next` loop this time, because it's an array) will be much faster than hitting the worksheet for every single cell (and hitting every cell multiple times, too).

Comment: Why not a `CountIf` formula in Line3? Something like `=COUNTIF(1:1,A2)` and pull it across? BTW you say "Line" but `Line1 = Range(Cells(4, 7), Cells(7, final_col))` is not a line `It is a block of cells which is 3 rows thick`.same is with `Line2`?  If it is not a single row then you will have to adjust the formula accordingly when the "range" in your countif formula will be a constant range using `$`